# Smooth scrolling does not work

Tags: javascript

I want to do that when you click on the link scroll smoothly moves up. But somehow setTimeout does not work. Here's the code:

```
window.onscroll = function(e) {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    a.style.opacity = (window.pageYOffset > document.documentElement.clientHeight) ? 1 : 0;
}

document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick = top;

function top() {
    if(window.pageYOffset != 0){
        window.scrollBy(0, -10);
        setTimeout(top, 100);
    }
}
```

Link to the sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/b7by1so8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As icktoofay answered, you have to use `preventDefault` to cancel the default behaviour of the link.

To go further, you might also want to stop the animation if the user has scrolled. To do so, you can save the position of the scroll every time you change it and if the next time it doesn't match, then you have to stop the animation.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/b7by1so8/1/

As said in this fiddle you can also use a decelarating speed to make things less linear by multiplicating scrollTop by a "slightly-less-to-1" number instead of just decrementing it.

Comment: Thanks you! Then try to understand itself.

Answer (score 1):

The default action upon clicking a link with a href of `#` is to bring the user to the top of the page. Since you did not call `preventDefault` on that event, the browser goes ahead and does it. You probably want to prevent it so you can do it yourself:

```
function top(e) {
    if(e) e.preventDefault();
    // ...
}
```